# jquery ajax data sending not working with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

i'm trying to send some data from jquery ( $.ajax ) to php file but it doesn't work.
in the success function it always shows the right answer but when i verify the POST in php file
with var_dump it shows an empty string.
i tried to replace $.ajax with $.post and $.get but none of them works.
here is my jquery code :

```
$('#sbt').on('click', function() {
    var email = $('#lgEmail').val();
    var pass = $('#lgPassword').val();
    $.ajax('../loginRegister.php', {
        type: 'GET', // http method
        data: {
            mail: email,
        }, // data to submit
        error:console.error,
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("done")
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage)
        }
    });
})
```

and here is my php code :

```
if (isset($_POST['mail'])){
    echo $_POST['mail'];
}
```

Comment: `type: 'GET'` != `$_POST['mail']`. Make sure you understand the difference between GET and POST methods with HTTP requests. If your PHP expects to receive POST data, then your jQuery needs to send a POST request...simple. So `type: 'POST'` should do the job.  :-)

Comment: that was a mistake i made but still not working

Comment: "not working" means what exactly? Debugging info please....explain what you expected to happen and what actually happens instead.

Comment: Bear in mind that you haven't actually written any code to see the response from your PHP, so if you want to check what PHP echoes you'll need to look in your browser's Network tool and find the request to loginRegister.php, click on it and then examine the raw output in the Response tab

Comment: FYI you have two `error:` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `type: 'GET'` you need to retrieve the parameter using `$_GET['mail']`.

You could also use `$_REQUEST['mail']`. `$_REQUEST` combines the parameters from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: i tried that but no result

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't display the echoed response. How are you verifying this?